# How can I get the Chinese Plants vs. Zombies 2 on iOS without jailbreak

Tags: ios, iphone

I have been trying to get the Chinese version of [Plants vs. Zombies 2](https://itunes.apple.com/de/app/plants-vs.-zombies-2/id597986893?mt=8). I use an iPhone 5c iOS 9.2. I will do just about anything but I do not want to jailbreak or lose any in app purchases I made with my American account.

Comment: I am having trouble creating an account since I don't have an credit card to fill it out and I'm not getting the none option. Thank you for answering

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Chinese Apple ID to download free content without a Chinese payment method, however you stated that…

> I do not want to … lose any in app purchases I made with my American account.

You can't do this regardless of whether you create a Chinese Apple ID.